# Exception type: ArgumentException Exception message: fullName

Tags: iis, forms-authentication, sharepoint-2016

I'm trying to Get FBA working on SharePoint 2016 BUT I am falling over at the last hurrdle.

The the problem occurs when after i have set all the web configs and machine configs, then set up my web app as for FBA with my role providers/membership providers.

I go into SharePoint site and log in with windows auth but i get the following error [Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tBOT.png)

The Same error is repeated in the event logs and only happens in the web app with FBA active and .net roles and .net users set with a default provider. PLEASE HELP I'm actually going mad now.

Thanks

[ROLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Txw.png)
[MEMBERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REsIa.png)

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] (or as close as you can get) of your code. From the error, it seems like your problem is related to the String variable `fullName`. Without looking at your code there's no way for us to see what could be going wrong.

Comment: Difficult to do this as the Strings are very large. But the -fullname is referance to a string in the sharepoint.dll. It feels like it can't auth claims based providers while it's set for FBA?

Comment: <add name="FBAMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="FBADB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />

Comment: <add name="FBARoleProvider" connectionStringName="FBADB" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

Comment: The above are from the machine config file. these are mirrored in the security token config as well.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that in Machine Config needs the FBAmembers setting up while in the Web config you need this:-
WEB CONFIG
[CODE for Web Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IORr.png)
And this fixed the issue.